# Vim function to find pattern, replace, and visual mode

Tags: vim

So I use Vim to write reports at work, reports are basically a bunch of "common issues" that we write over and over, so they are templated. These templates have placeholder blocks `{==BLOCK==}` to ensure people modify things as/when needed, so this is an example:

```
The test revealed that it was possible to access {==sensitive data==},
as shown in the examples below...
```

That block may need to be modified, or not. So the idea is, I am editing the common issue, and I see there are 3 or 4 blocks like the one in the example, I'd like to press let's say [leader]b and then end up having the template text for the first block selected in visual mode without the `{==` and `==}` that are around it.

I have tried a few things but I didn't get too far, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express myself properly, but I dont want to replace with a REGEX what is inside, I'd like the function to find the block, get rid of {== and ==} and then leave the template text inside the block as it is, but selected in visual mode

Answer (score 3):

You could define the following function:

```
function! VisualSelect()                                                 
    call search("==}")                                                      
    norm hvT=                                                             
endfunction                                                                 
nnoremap <leader>b :call VisualSelect()<cr> 
vnoremap <leader>b Ol<esc>:call VisualSelect()<cr>
```

This will visually select the contents between `{==` and `==}`. Typing `<leader>b` repeatedly will select the next occurrence.

Comment: Use `xnoremap` to allow this only in visual mode instead of also picking select mode.

Answer (score 0):

Most template/snippet expand plugins support this.

With my [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets) plugin, you can execute

```
:SetMarkers {== ==}
```

and then jump from one placeholder to the next with `CTRL+J` with vim, or `META-DEL` with gvim. [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets) doesn't take care of loading/expanding templates. [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template) will add this layer.

If instead you choose to use one of the more popular snippet plugin, there will certainly be an option to change the syntax of the placeholders, but I don't know it.

The poor man's solution would look like:

```
nnoremap <c-j> <c-\><c-n>/{==.*==}<cr>v/==}/e<cr><c-g>
snoremap <c-j> <c-\><c-n>/{==.*==}<cr>v/==}/e<cr><c-g>
```

but it won't take care of restoring the search pattern, of the cases where the cursor is already within a placeholder, and so on...

EDIT: the version that automatically deletes the placeholder marks is

```
nnoremap <c-j> <c-\><c-n>/{==.*==}<cr>v/==}/e<cr>s<c-r>=matchstr(@", '{==\zs.*\ze==}')<cr><esc>gv6h<c-g>
```

- the same in `snoremap`

Comment: Thanks, but using 2 plugins just for this task seems a bit overkill to me!


Regarding "the poor man's solution", the problem is that it doesn't delete the {== and ==} bits, which is part of what I'd like to automate.

Thanks!

Comment: The second part is easy enough to accomplish, once in visual mode, replace with (`s<c-r>=`) the inner part (with `matchstr` or  `substitute()`), and then reselect (`gv`), fix the end (`6h`) and go to select mode (`<c-g>`). 
`nnoremap <c-j> <c-\><c-n>/{==.*==}<cr>v/==}/e<cr>s<c-r>=matchstr(@", '{==\zs.*\ze==}')<cr><esc>gv6h<c-g>`
But actually, the select-mode is more than enough in most use cases as in the end the placeholder must be replaced with something different of the placeholder description.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
nnoremap <leader>b /{==.*==}<cr>xxxvt=<esc>/==}<cr>xxxgv
```

What it does:

1.) find the pattern

```
/{==.*==}<cr>
```

2.) Remove the first "{=="

```
xxx
```

3.) Visual select your text until the first = (maybe this could be also optimized for using a regex instead of simple searching for the next =)

```
vt=
```

4.) Go to the end sequence

```
/==}<cr>
```

5.) Remove it

```
xxx
```

6.) Select again your last selection

```
gv
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way based on what @snap said, I ended up adding the code to a Python plugin to run it through it, as that fits better with what I am trying to do, snippet below:

```
@neovim.command('VimisEditTemplateBlock')
def urlify(self):
    """Search next codify block and prepare for editing"""
[...]
    self.nvim.command('call search("{==")') # Find beginning of codify block
    self.nvim.command('norm xxx') # Delete {==
    self.nvim.command('norm vf=') # Select the inner text
    self.nvim.command('norm v')
    self.nvim.command('norm xxxgvh') #Delete ==} and leave the inner text selected in Visual Mode
```